# Adding an icon to the windows console application

Tags: c#

Is there any way to add an icon to a windows console application (that will be displayed in folders and in the task bar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project Properties and select an icon.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the OP spec'd C#, but I came here looking for the same answer for C+, so I thought I'd post that answer.
To set an app icon for a C++ console app, you add a .RC file to the project, then add an .ico to the .rc, then recompile. The .ico will automatically become the app's icon.